# Spark df.select returning incorrect columns for csv with headers

Tags: scala, csv, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, columnheader

I am implementing the buildScan method of Spark Data Source API v1.

```
override def buildScan(requiredColumns: Array[String], filters: Array[Filter]): RDD[Row] =
```

I am trying to read a .csv file with headers.

```
val df = sqlContext.sparkSession.read
     .schema(_schema_)
     .option("header", "true")
     .csv(_array_pf_paths_)
```

and returning it as an rdd

```
df.rdd
```

The schema is as follows:

```
root
|-- A: string (nullable = true)
|-- B: string (nullable = true)
|-- C: string (nullable = true)
|-- D: string (nullable = true)
|-- E: string (nullable = true)
|-- F: string (nullable = true)
```

Headers appear in the header position as well as the first row

```
df.show()

-----------------------
A   B   C   D   E   F
-----------------------
A   B   C   D   E   F
a1  b1  c1  d1  e1  f1 
a2  b2  c2  d2  e2  f2 
a3  b3  c3  d3  e3  f3 
a4  b4  c4  d4  e4  f4 
a5  b5  c5  d5  e5  f5 
------------------------
```

Once the rdd is returned as I do

```
df.select(F) or df.select(E)
```

always the first column is returned.

```
---
A   
---
A   
a1
a2
a3
a4
a5
---
```

but df.show inside of buildScan() returns the correct column.

I am not able to find where exactly the column mapping is going wrong.

Answer (score 0):

you have to use double quote in column name
like df.select("D").show()

Comment: thanks. that was a typo in the post. i do have quotes around the column name.